# PHP ereg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, ereg-replace

I have this file that I am uploading to the server via php file upload..

```
6;'!8.jpg
```

I used this code to remove non alphanumeric characters..

```
$image1 = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

that works fine, but it returns my image like this

```
68jpg
```

What would be the best way to return this as `68.jpg`

Any ideas?

Comment: ereg* is deprecated. Use preg* instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ereg/eregi. These functions are deprecated. Use [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) functions instead.

Try this way

`$image1 = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9\.]#i", null, $_FILES["image"]["name"]);`

Comment: Nice for repairing the regexp :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
$image1 = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9\\.]", "", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

But you should really try to use `preg_` instead of `ereg_` PHP functions as they are more performant (and not deprecated).

Comment: This still won't work - check Your regexp. It should be with one backslash: `[^A-Za-z0-9\.]`. Your regexp would allow alphanums, a backslash and then any character (cos You did escaped a backslash and an unescaped dot means anything)...

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use PHP's pathinfo($_IMAGE["image"]["name"]) command to break apart a filename's base path, base name and file extension.  You can then run your search n' replace (as @John Conde recommends) on the basename, then concatenate the basename and file extension back together.

Comment: Why do it this complicated? -1

Comment: The problem is that many people solves problems with overcomplicated solutions... Why to use `pathinfo`, then break sth apart and then use the `preg_replace` anyway when it could be used with instant result.